Asparagus in the fall
It's September 9th 2024 and I am working on a job in an asparagus field. Some of the asparagus they cut off to ground level and yet it's still growing spears. Can I break these spears off and eat them or wouldn't that be good.

It depends.  If you are asking whether or not this is safe for you, it is.  There is no reason that this asparagus is any different from the rest.  On the other hand, this might not be good for the asparagus plant itself and for the farm. The spears are the stem of the plant.  Harvesting too many or too many times in a season can damage the health of the plant.  Here is some good information on the topic. There might be an economic reason for these spears to be left in place.

Yeah, we grew asparagus when I was young, and the key was that you had to stop harvesting to let the plant go to seed for it to come back happy and healthy the next year. I suspect if someone was being paid to work in an asparagus field and they kept harvesting after the season for personal use, the employer would be fairly unhappy since that is likely to directly affect the next season a growth (and since asparagus comes back year after year, that could be quite significant in the long run).

usually you stop harvesting it way before now... I'm surprised they cut it unless it was someone who didn't know what they were doing.  (maybe if they were trying to rid it of pests or some disease?)  It's like flower bulbs where it needs to put reserves into the ground so it can come back strong next year
